# Как сделать выбор между тремя типами сортировки?

Tags: c++

Написал программу для сортировки тремя типами, а еще нужно сделать так, чтобы я мог сам задать рамки сортировки, от какого элемента к какому... (Допустим у меня есть 7 элементов [3, 12, 7, 1, 9, 19, 32], и я хочу отсортировать от 3 элемента - 7, к 6 элементу - 19).

main.cpp:

```cpp
#include "sort.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const int n = 5;
    int x[n] = { 4,2,1,3,5 };
    int i, a, j, min;
    a = 0; j = 0; min = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        cout << x[i] << "   ";
    cout << "\n  ";

    cout << "\n    SortBubble" << endl;

    SortBubble(i, j, a, x, n);
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        cout << x[i] << "   "; cout << "\n  ";


    cout << "\n  SortInsertion" << endl;

    SortInsertion(i, j, a, x, n);
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        cout << x[i] << "   "; cout << "\n  ";


    cout << "\n   SortSelection" << endl;

    SortSelection(i, j, a, min, x, n);
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        cout << x[i] << "   ";
}
```

Sort.cpp:

```cpp
#include "Sort.h"
void SortBubble(int i, int j, int a, int x[], const int n)
{
    for (j = 1; j < n; j++) // цикл кроків сортування
        for (i = 0; i < n - j; i++) // цикл порівняння елементів і іх перестановки
            if (x[i] > x[i + 1])
            {
                a = x[i];
                x[i] = x[i + 1];
                x[i + 1] = a;
            };
};
void SortInsertion(int i, int j, int a, int x[], const int n)
{

    for (i = 1; i < n; i++)
    {
        a = x[i];
        for (j = i - 1; j >= 0 && x[j] > a; j--)
        {
            x[j + 1] = x[j];
            x[j] = a;
        }
    };
}
void SortSelection(int i, int j, int a, int min, int x[], const int n)
{
    for (i = 0; i < (n - 1); i++) {
        int min = i;
        for (j = i; j < n; j++) {
            if (x[j] < x[min])
            {
                min = j;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Sort.h

```cpp
#pragma once

void SortBubble(int i, int j, int a, int x[], const int n);
void SortInsertion(int i, int j, int a, int x[], const int n);
void SortSelection(int i, int j, int a, int min, int x[], const int n);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для начала уберите лишние параметры - `i,j,a` - используйте локальные переменные.

Потом добавьте границы сортировки (например, `lo, hi`), и примените их в качестве границ циклов.

На примере сортировки вставками:

```
void SortInsertion(int x[], const int n, int lo, int hi)
{

    for (int i = lo + 1; i <= hi; i++) 
    {
       int a = x[i];
       for (int j = i - 1; j >= lo && x[j] > a; j--)
       {
           x[j + 1] = x[j];
           x[j] = a;
       }
   };
}
```

И проверьте работоспособность ваших функций - например, сортировка выбором ничего не делает.